# Change the colour of cells with prime numbers in a dynamic table created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So far I have created the code to generate a table that has the number of cells that is defined by the user. In addition to this, the cells which have the prime numbers in it, must be coloured in a different colour. I have also included a function to find the prime numbers, but the approach I took to create the table, doesn't give me an option to implement the function onto the html body.
I would really appreciate any help.

Here's my code..

```
<html>
  <head>
     <style>
            table{width: 70%;}
     </style>
     <script>
        const numString= window.prompt("What is the loop maximum.? (between 1 and 500)")
        let num=parseInt(numString);
        if(num<0 || num>500)
        {
            window.alert("Warning! Must be between 1 and 500. Setting to default 
            100")
            num=100
        }
        function isPrime(num)
        {
            for(var i=2; i< num; i++)
                if(num % i ===0) return false;
            return num>1;
        }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Javascript Loops and Functions</h1><br>
    <script>
        document.write("<table border=1>");
        let rows = num % 10 >= 0 && num % 10 <= 10 ? num / 10 + 1 : num / 10;
        let count = 0; 
        for (row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
          document.write("<tr>");
          for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (count >= num+1) break;
            document.write("<td>" + count + "</td>");
            count++;
          }
          document.write("</tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table>");
    </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS class to give colors. For instance `prime_true` could be the class for prime numbers and `prime_false` for non-primes.

It is not so good practice to use `document.write` for such a purpose. So I would suggest to have an empty table element in your HTML, and then use loops to populate that table with rows and cells:

```js
function isPrime(num) {
    for(var i=2; i< num; i++)
        if(num % i ===0) return false;
    return num>1;
}

let table = document.querySelector("table");
for (let line = 1; line <= 500; line += 10) {
    let row = table.insertRow();
    for (let i = line; i < line + 10; i++) {
        let td = row.insertCell();
        td.textContent = i;
        td.className = "prime_" + isPrime(i);
    }
}
```

```css
table { width: 70%; }
td { border: 1px solid; text-align: center }
.prime_true { background: orange }
.prime_false { background: lightgrey }
```

```html
<h1>Javascript Loops and Functions</h1><br>
<table></table>
```

NB: this script should be in a script element that is put below the `table` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (count >= num+1) break;
  if(isPrime(count)){
    document.write("<td style='background-color:red'>" + count + "</td>");
  } else {
    document.write("<td>" + count + "</td>");
  }
  count++;
}
```